# Spring Cloud Config: define server config properties programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have self-configured Spring Cloud Config server (it uses itself for its own configuration).

So basically I have a single file `bootstrap.properties` with the content:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=<my GitHub repo>
spring.application.name=config
spring.profiles.active=development
```

It works well, but I want to define the properties above using Java code. In fact, I can keep those properties there, I just want to add `spring.cloud.config.server.git.username` and `spring.cloud.config.server.git.password` programmatically. Is it possible to do it somehow?

I tried using common approaches for adding/overriding of Spring properties defined in `application.properties`, but haven't succeeded: looks like `bootstrap.properties` should be declared programmatically in some other way (if it's even possible).

Comment: bootstrap.properties is one of the first thing spring framework reads. i don't think you can add to it programatically. But i believe you can pass that value from command line(if you dont want to put it in properties file)

Comment: @pvpkiran That was my first thought. But then I came up with a "hackish" solution, please, find it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some digging into Spring sources, I've managed to find a solution. I don't like it because it looks like a dirty hack, but at least it works. I would appreciate if anyone proposes a cleaner solution.

resources/META-INF/spring.factories:

```
# Bootstrap components
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
my.awesome.package.ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration
```

ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigServerProperties server;

    @Bean
    public MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository environmentRepository() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap", "true");
        properties.put("spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri", "<GitHub repo URI>");
        properties.put("spring.cloud.config.server.git.username", "username");
        properties.put("spring.cloud.config.server.git.password", "password");
        properties.put("spring.application.name", "config");
        properties.put("spring.profiles.active", "development");
        MapPropertySource customPropertySource = new MapPropertySource("applicationConfig: [classpath:/bootstrap.properties]", properties);
        environment.getPropertySources().replace("applicationConfig: [classpath:/bootstrap.properties]", customPropertySource);
        MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository repository = new MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository(this.environment);
        if (this.server.getDefaultLabel() != null) {
            repository.setDefaultLabel(this.server.getDefaultLabel());
        }
        return repository;
    }

}
```

P.S. It's also possible to add iteration over existing properties here to keep them as in the file (and possibly override).

P.P.S. I don't know why, but it worked only with the class name `ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration`. When I renamed it, it stopped working. I don't care much about the naming here though...

Comment: why do you call it a dirty hack?

Comment: Firstly, I believe it's cumbersome: usually, Spring provides more smooth ways of configuring things. Why the hell should I know about some `spring.factories`? I never used it before and ideally I'd prefer to keep not knowing about this file :) Secondly, I couldn't find an easy way of _adding_ properties to existing ones: I had to iterate over existing properties and copy them to the new map manually, then add a couple of my own, and then re-set this map. I also think that it's a bit of a hassle and not elegant at all.

Comment: No bean availible for ConfigServerProperties. MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository() takes 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you prefer:

```
properties.put("spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri", "<GitHub repo URI>");
properties.put("spring.cloud.config.server.git.username", "username");
properties.put("spring.cloud.config.server.git.password", "password");
```

to add them to `bootstrap.yml`?

or set them via VM args (`.... -Dspring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=xxxxxx ....`) or via env variables (`... SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_URI=xxxxx .... java -jar application.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

Try below in your bootstrap.yml

```
    username: ${SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME:defaultuser}
    password: ${SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD:defaultpass}
```

And add the values as environments variable for-

```
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD
```